Bi-LSTM accuracy not improving at all
I am fairly new to deep learning in general and I apologize if this is a rookie mistake. I am trying to replicate a Bi-LSTM model to perform a binary classification process on extracted EEG features (positive or negative emotion) using the GAMEEMO dataset. My data has 112 rows and 71 columns. I am currently facing a problem whereby my accuracy won't increase no matter what I do. The highest that I've gotten is 73.91% but it always changes with each run (think I only got that once) and now it's stuck between 30-ish% to 50-ish%. I know that a general rule would be for the accuracy to increase and loss to decrease in the training but mine is fluctuating. I've tried plotting the ROC curve and I know that the shape is off but I can't pinpoint why. Is my code problematic?
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Bidirectional, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Izwan\Desktop\JupyterLab\1 - Feature Extraction\Φ- Labeled Files\labeled-spectral.csv")

data = data.drop(['subject', 'game', 'class'], axis=1)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data['emotion'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['emotion'])

X = data.drop(['emotion'], axis=1)
y = data['emotion']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train = X_train.values.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
X_test = X_test.values.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(1, X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
optim = keras.optimizers.SGD()
metrics = ("accuracy")

model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optim, metrics=[metrics])

batch_size = 64
epochs = 100
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

y_pred_prob = model.predict(X_test).ravel()
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_prob)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=2, label=f'ROC curve (area = {roc_auc:.2f})')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=2, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show() ```

[![Excerpt from data][1]][1]

[![Results][2]][2]

[![ROC curve][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/TpGvFDUJ.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/A2QIDNb8.png
  [3]: https://i.sstatic.net/M62zzAYp.png

